# System.IO.FileNotFoundException at Program.Main()

Tags: c#, filenotfoundexception

Normally I don't have any problems by fixing this error but in this case I simply can't find a reason for this exception.

In the evenviewer it just says:

> Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The process was terminated
>   due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException at Program.Main()

Because I don't do any FileSystem related stuff in Main(). I tried to debug by using just a few MessageBoxes popping up after each executed line but even when the first line is a simple messagebox with "hello" in it, it crashs with the same error..

Comment: add the code what you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is in `Main` but it doesn't probably occurs in your code but it is caused by your code.

It looks like one of the required dll(s) is missing. You could try running this application with [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/) that will log all the dll's that are loaded and investigate on which one the exception occurs or try [FusLogVw](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.110).aspx) that should also give you an indication of what's missing.

Comment: I am referring to the CefSharp browser. It looks like it's no longer loading. (I installed it using NuGet). Do you know how to fix this? It's just confusing me because this exception appeard from one day to another without installing/uninstall anything or changing code..

Comment: @IchBestäube I see you've marked the answer. Just out of curiosity - what was it?

Comment: For CefSharp a special version of the vc++ redistributable (vc++ 2013 x86) is required. On the test computer I tried to run my program is was missing..